# Date constructor works differently whether Chrome Debugger is attached

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having a very strange issue here. JS is evaluating `new Date("6-1-2013")` differently depending on whether I have the debugger attached or not. I'm running a React Native app in Expo.

These are the results for running the following from my code:

```
console.log('new Date("6-1-2013"),', new Date("6-1-2013"));
```

With debugger:

```
new Date("6-1-2013"), 2013-06-01T04:00:00.000Z
```

Without debugger:

```
new Date("6-1-2013"), Date { NaN }
```

**Update**: Passing "June 1, 2013" to the constructor works with or without the debugger. So my particular issue at the moment is fixed.

I still want to know why this would happen differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by different JavaScript Environments. Look at the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html):

> ## JavaScript Runtime
>
> When using React Native, you're going to be running your JavaScript
> code in two environments:
>
> - In most cases, React Native will use JavaScriptCore, the JavaScript engine that powers Safari. Note that on iOS, JavaScriptCore
>   does not use JIT due to the absence of writable executable memory in
>   iOS apps.
> - When using Chrome debugging, all JavaScript code runs within Chrome itself, communicating with native code via WebSockets. Chrome
>   uses V8 as its JavaScript engine.
>
> While both environments are very similar, you may end up hitting some
> inconsistencies. We're likely going to experiment with other
> JavaScript engines in the future, so it's best to avoid relying on
> specifics of any runtime.

The problem is that the date constructor is really picky, so you need to be careful on how you are creating dates.

A popular workaround is to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Moment.js will handle all the date transformations in background for you and it will work on all platforms, javascript engines etc.

Install moment.js with:

```
npm --install moment
```

and then you can replace:

```
 new Date("6-1-2013")
```

with:

```
import Moment from 'moment';

//second parameter is the specified format of your date string  

const date = Moment("6-1-2013", "M-D-YYYY");
```